# Basemap drawcountries() not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm simply trying to plot a map and add the borders of the countries.
Here is the code snipped:

```
map=Basemap(projection="lcc",resolution="l",width=1E6,height=1E6,lon_0=9.9167,lat_0=51.5167,fix_aspect=False)
map.drawcounties(zorder=1,color="black")
map.shadedrelief()
map.drawcoastlines(color="black",linewidth=2)
map.drawrivers(linewidth=0.5,color="blue")
map.drawmapboundary()
```

Everything is working besides the borders....There is also no 
Error...it simply does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Additionaly the resolution of the map is a bit blurred. Is there any way to boost the resolution?

Thanks for your answers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw to borders of the count**r**ies you need `drawcountries`.   (Mind the **`r`**)
To draw to borders of the counties you need `drawcounties`.
Note however that the german Bundesländer are no "counties" in the sense of the basemap, so it will not draw them.

To get a higher resolution try `resolution="i"` in the Basemap initialization.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map=Basemap(projection="lcc",resolution="i",width=1E6,height=1E6,
                             lon_0=9.9167,lat_0=51.5167,fix_aspect=False)
map.drawcountries(zorder=1,color="black", linewidth=1)
map.shadedrelief()
map.drawcoastlines(color="black",linewidth=1.2)
map.drawrivers(linewidth=0.5,color="blue")
map.drawmapboundary()

plt.show()
```

[image]